# Optimal database schema structure

Tags: mysql, laravel, greatest-n-per-group, query-performance

I am building a **forum** web application on Laravel.

While users are on topics page, **every topic** will be shown with additional relation datas, such as **number of posts** in the topic, **last post** even the **author of the last post** of the topic.

Given the fact that there will be **deeply nested relational datas** with every topic, is it okay to **access these properties via relationships** or I should store these datas in **separate columns** of the topics table in order to achieve *normal* performance?

I know it would be better to **store the datas directly in the parent table**, but **MUST I**? What is a best practice in terms of **performance** and  **normalization**?

Comment: What's a deeply nested relational data?

Comment: A topic has posts. A post belongs to a user. A user has a badge. Now fetching 50 topics with their first and last posts along with their corresponding badges requires to access 4th level of relationship for every topic. I mean this, when I say deeply nested relational datas. Is there a proper name for it?

Comment: Following a relationship is not going "deeper".  Think of it as going laterally.  Does a user have only one badge?  "First and last, plus ..." implies "groupwise-max".  I'm adding a tag for such.

Comment: In think in terms of JSON response. That’s why I use the term “deep”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice in terms normalization would be to get all data via relationships.

In terms of performance, you should be caching anything that is costly to compute.

I'd write a scheduled job that updates the cache with fresh data for all topics every few minutes.

Here's more information on Laravel's [caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache) and [task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling).

Comment: Sounds good to me. If there will not any better solution to the problem, I will check this one as the solution. But I wonder if caching itself can slow down the server or not.

Comment: I am analyzing database structure of Invision Community and finding out there is plenty of such types of columns in the tables which contain datas about relational models. It is possible to look up inside of almost every items while hovering over them. Is it because they use less optimal framework than Laravel or just don’t want to change database structure?

Comment: To start with, simply use the caching that goes along with the database.  Don't invent your own; it will be "premature optimization".

Comment: Any framework adds complexity -- It limits your ability to get at the power of the underlying database engine, while requiring you to learn both the RDBMS _and_ the framework.